# Make read only disk partition for data archive in windows, change to writable and vice-versa in Linux

Tags: linux, windows

When i archive data in windows i have to OFF read-only bit first of desired disk volume(using diskpart utility), check-in the data and turn ON read-only bit. Now same way i want to archive data in Linux based system(preferably Debian 9) on same disk volume and maintaining compatible with Windows.

So, current scenario is first make disk volume writable in windows, check-in data in Linux, make disk volume back to read-only in windows.

Do any one know how to make disk volume writable in Linux which has been marked as read-only by Windows (using diskpart utility)?

What i understand windows make read-only disk volume at disk driver level but Linux make read-only disk volume as per rule defined in fstab.

I am also open for suggestion for other ways of archiving which can is better way than current scenario without compromising integrity of archived data.

FYI, I am using external drive for archive (it have 4 partition with some are exFat rest are NTFS), windows 10 and debian 9. Data in question are in form of videos, documents(doc,docx and pdf) and images.